# Set optionset value for custom entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I'd like to setting the optionset value for CRM with attribute type is PicklistAttributeMetadata:

```
//Executing Status
                    CreateAttributeRequest executingStatusAttributeRequest =
                        new CreateAttributeRequest
                        {
                            EntityName = customEntityName,
                            Attribute = new PicklistAttributeMetadata
                            {
                                SchemaName = prefix + "executingstatus",
                                DisplayName = new Label("Executing Status", 1033),
                                OptionSet = new OptionSetMetadata
                                 {
                                     IsGlobal = false,
                                     OptionSetType = OptionSetType.Picklist,
                                     Options =  { 
                                        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Draft",1033),null),
                                        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Executing",1033),null),
                                        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Complete (No Errors)",1033),null),
                                        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Complete (Errors)",1033),null)
                                    }
                                 }
                            }
                        };
                    CreateAttributeResponse executingStatusAttributeResponse =
                        (CreateAttributeResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(
                        executingStatusAttributeRequest);
```

How to I set the 'dh_executingstatus' with value is 'Draft':

```
Entity dhEntity = new Entity(customEntityName);
```

`dhEntity["dh_executingstatus"]=???`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to give each option you create it's own unique integer value:

```
Options =  { 
    new OptionMetadata(new Label("Draft",1033),1),
    new OptionMetadata(new Label("Executing",1033),2),
    new OptionMetadata(new Label("Complete (No Errors)",1033),3),
    new OptionMetadata(new Label("Complete (Errors)",1033),4)
}
```

Then you'll need to publish the entity.  Then, when working with a record, you can update the optionset value like this:

```
ent["dh_executingstatus"] = new OptionSetValue(2);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you save my time. :)